Error desconocido luego del proceso de instalación dual en notebook 24.04.1 LTS
Mensaje del aviso:
SE PRODUJO UN PROBLEMA
Lo sentimos, pero no estamos seguros de cual sea el error.
ese el aviso que me sale luego de hacer todos los pasos correspondientes a la instalacion booteable desde un pendrive
alguno le paso?

apologies. This is an English only site. Please [edit] your question accordingly.

In addition to what @graham has pointed out, you have included the 20.04 tag, but your question mentions 24.04.1 LTS

I got the same error when trying with Ubuntu 24.04 and for Ubuntu 22.04 Security Violation on booting from a USB thumb drive.
I found no answers.

I did the following:
verify that after the Ubuntu 24.04.1 installation error when removing the live USB and restarting the system Ubuntu starts correctly
only one error in sudo apt update, you delete the data from the /etc/apt/sources.list file and from Software & Updates, you change to the main server and update,
after sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade some packages are retained, you install them manually with sudo apt install
Everything is updated and working so far in a dual boot with Windows 11.

Another option you have is not to connect to the internet and the installation finishes correctly, but do not force updates of the retained packages with sudo apt install because they generate an error with the brightness control, just update sudo apt update
